# Snowflake python sheet store file at stage

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following small test, where I would like to store a xlsx file at internal stage in snowflake:

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col

def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
# Your code goes here, inside the "main" handler.
tableName = 'information_schema.packages'
dataframe = session.table(tableName).filter(col("language") == 'python')

x = dataframe.to_pandas()
unload_location = "@JV_TEST/jv.xlsx"

x.to_excel(unload_location)
# Print a sample of the dataframe to standard output.
dataframe.show()

# Return value will appear in the Results tab.
return dataframe
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Worksheet, line 17, in main
  File "pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 211, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 211, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "pandas/core/generic.py", line 2374, in to_excel
    formatter.write(
  File "pandas/io/formats/excel.py", line 944, in write
    writer = ExcelWriter(  # type: ignore[abstract]
  File "pandas/io/excel/_xlsxwriter.py", line 205, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 1313, in __init__
    self._handles = get_handle(
  File "pandas/io/common.py", line 734, in get_handle
    check_parent_directory(str(handle))
  File "pandas/io/common.py", line 597, in check_parent_directory
    raise OSError(rf"Cannot save file into a non-existent directory: '{parent}'")
OSError: Cannot save file into a non-existent directory: '@JV_TEST'
```

How can I store the file at stage? (I would like to use pandas and xlsxwrite, because I would like to apply some stuff to the excel sheet)

Answer (score 2):

At this time it is not possible to write to a stage using Python Worksheets.
The general limitations from Python Stored Procedures and [UDFs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf-stored-procedure-security-practices#practices-for-procedure-and-udf-handlers) apply also to Python Worksheets.

This means you can only write files to `/tmp` and once your session is terminated the files won't be accessible anymore from `/tmp`.
You can only write to `/tmp` using Python's built in functions like `open()`, it doesn't work with external ones like `xlsxwriter`.

As a general rule, manipulations of files stored on a stage using Python is not possible.

Comment: It does not look like it is possible to write to / tmp
`xlsxwriter.exceptions.FileCreateError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted`

Comment: You're right, I just checked. It's only possible for something like `with open(unload_location, "w") as file:
      file.write("Test")` but not from within `xlsxwriter`.

Comment: One of other other options would be to export using [DataFrameWriter](https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/api/snowflake.snowpark.DataFrameWriter.copy_into_location.html#snowflake-snowpark-dataframewriter-copy-into-location), but you can only do CSV.

Comment: `with pd.ExcelWriter("/tmp/hest.xlsx", engine="openpyxl") as writer:
        x.to_excel(writer)

session.file.put("/tmp/hest.xlsx", "@JV_TEST", auto_compress=False)`

This works.